# "error: specified package has no binaries" when trying to install packages with cargo?

Tags: installation, rust, rust-cargo

I've made a new project with

```
cargo new project-name
cd ./project-name
```

And once in the directory running

```
cargo install crate-name
```

for any crate listed on crates.io yields the error

```
Updating crates.io index
Installing crate-name version-number                                                    
error: specified package has no binaries
```

Looking elsewhere suggests adding the proper dependencies to my Cargo.toml file, but this does not change the output I'm getting. In particular I'm trying to install rust-gmp as a project dependency, and having

```
[dependencies]
rust-gmp = "0.5.0"
```

in Cargo.toml does not allow me to install rust-gmp. Any suggestions?

Comment: The command is `cargo build` for building the project, `cargo run` for running the main binary application, and `cargo install` to install the local project. `cargo install crate-name` only works if the crate is already published on [crates.io](//crates.io). See also the Cargo guide on [creating a new package](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/creating-a-new-project.html).

Comment: Trying to install rust-gmp as a dependency for my project. It seems to be listed on crates.io (https://crates.io/crates/rust-gmp)

Comment: Done. I get the same error for any crate listed on crates.io though; I can't seem to install any crate as a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies are not actually "installed", by Cargo's nomenclature. Instead, as you already did, you add the crate as a dependency of a project in *Cargo.toml*.

Thus, whenever you run a subcommand which requires those dependencies in some way (e.g `cargo build`, `cargo check`, `cargo run`, etc.), they will be automatically downloaded and compiled for you.

See also the [Cargo guide on managing dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/dependencies.html).

Comment: Thanks! Figured out the problem, needed to write `extern crate gmp;` in place of `extern crate rust-gmp;` when importing the package.